# Egypt bug needs identification please

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Is it possible to identify this bug,,? Found in South Sinai  .in Egypt . Only seen crawling but maybe it can fly ? Black with 6 legs. 2 long black "strings " coming from back end 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the 2 long black "strings" are from the back? Looks more like an antenna to me, and the larger legs are usually on the back.

Comment: Please update with approximate size and a picture of the other side of the specimen. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a **cricket** in the family [Gryllidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_(insect)). The two thin "strings" on the left are [antennae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna), and the two sturdier "strings" on the right are [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus) (though your image is not clear, and perhaps one of the extensions on the right is actually an [ovipositor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovipositor)). See [here](http://cricketcare.org/anatomy/) for a clear image showing cricket anatomy.

An example cricket with wide geographic range that includes Egypt:

[*Gryllus bimaculatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gryllus_bimaculatus)

[image]

<sup>Credit: [Vlad Proklov](http://wonder-cabinet.sites.gettysburg.edu/2017/cabinet/small-asian-wonders/)</sup>

Without additional info, I'm not sure you'll get an accurate species ID on your specimen.

Comment: All photos on this question are of female specimens (yes, that _is_ an ovipositor on the right; the right cercus is also visible just below, but somewhat out of focus); given that species level identification in singing insects is at least assisted by a recording of the male calling song, the best anyone will be able to do is give a genus (assuming access to the specimen and the appropriate identification keys).

Comment: Thanks for the informative follow-up, Arthur.